# Accepted a job offer and asked for my name to be corrected on the job offer then got no response

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I received a very good job offer Last Wednesday after conducting 3 interviews with HR, the Delivery Manager and the Program Manager. They were really nice and gave me extremely positive feedback, and even said they can't wait for me to join the team.

HR called me before sending the offer and said that she wants me to reply on the same day. The start date was set to be October 1st, as we agreed.

I replied to her email, accepted the offer but I did not sign it as both my first and last name were written incorrectly. I accepted within the body of my email and asked them to correct the spelling of my names, so I can sign it. A day after I resigned and agreed with my boss that my last day will be August 31, so again I emailed HR and informed them with my updated availability date.

It's now been 5-6 days now and I have not got any reply, when should I start to worry and how often should I be contacting them? I don't wanna seem impatient or show that I want the job too much but I already resigned so there is no going back.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63462/discussion-on-question-by-rvnsotw-accepted-a-job-offer-and-asked-for-my-name-to).  Rvnsotw if you have updates, please [edit] them into the question. For further discussion take it to the linked chat room.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could turn out to be no issue, the employer set October as an acceptable start date, and you've updated to say beginning September, but there are big mistakes here:

1. Name - I would have crossed out the bad spelling, and fixed it, then signed.
2. Bigger point - I wouldn't have resigned until I had all paperwork sorted, dates agreed, and know there are no other conditions to the offer (background check, credit check?).  This goes triple as it sounds in comments like it's an international move.

It's not out the bounds they could go cold on you, given they wanted to get it fixed that day, and you sent the offer back unsigned.  I wouldn't email, but phone and find out the status.  You may find it's fine, but you may need to try and backpeddle at current job/ find a new job NOW.

In future don't jump until you know the net is really there, not just someone has said it will be if you agree to jump.

Comment: Yup - my current job went "cold" right about the time an offer was extended. I sent them an email saying that obviously they had "issues" (won't say -- I love working here now, it was just an HR vendor problem), then I got a call from my (now, current) manager saying there was obviously some issue.