# When is the correct time to resign during a job change?

Tags: job-change, human-resources, resignation

I am in my job changing period, currently serving my notice period. 2 weeks back, I have given an interview, the interview went pretty well that they wanted me to sign the contract immediately. I have asked them for some time to think it over and decide. They gave me the sample contract, so I can read and go through it! They informed me that once I talk to my boss and clear things up, I can sign the contract at their place.

It is a very good opportunity for me. So, I have decided to take it. I have talked to my current employer, he accepted my resignation without causing any trouble. Now, since last week my new employer (HR guy) is acting a bit weird. He hardly replies to my emails, never takes any calls. This might sound like, I am annoying them but I have asked them to clarify my salary package and raised a couple of concerns regarding what they have proposed. [so 2 emails, 4-5 phone call attempts over 3 days span]. I have finally settled with them this issue. He told me that he will prepare my contract and invite me for signing exactly 7 days back. It has been 10 days already that I have resigned and still I am waiting for the contract to sign! Here in Germany, we had a long weekend last week but HR clearly told me that it will be done by 02.05.2018. Yesterday, I wrote him an email and today I tried to call him and there is no response yet!

So, was it a mistake from me to resign the current job before signing the new contract? This is my first job change, so I am a bit worried if I have messed it up! Should I wait for their contract? or resume my job search again?

EDIT: Related Question: [Accepted a job offer and asked for my name to be corrected on the job offer then got no response](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96673/accepted-a-job-offer-and-asked-for-my-name-to-be-corrected-on-the-job-offer-then?rq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you did.

You do not have a signed job contract, so you do not have a new job. Period. You also terminated your old job.

The time to quit the old job is once you have a signature under the new job contract.

I would suggest you resume your job search immediately - there is a decent chance the contract may not come through. If it does, all you lost is a little time searhing.

Comment: Why are you saying that the contract may not come through? Could you explain, please?

Comment: Beause it may not come through. You raise a lot of warning signs yourself, including the other side not replying to your requests. I learned in my first work - there is no contract until it is signed.

Comment: That means I clearly messed it up! Luckily enough, I did not completely stop my job search. Thanks!

Comment: @Enthu_Learner I wouldn't give up on the new job *immediately* - I would at least pay a visit to the new office once you're finished with your notice period at the old office and try to get things sorted out in person.  Maybe that job is still available after all.  That said, I do agree with the bulk of this answer - you shouldn't resign until you've actually *signed* the new offer.

Comment: @Steve-O finally he wrote me an Email now, saying that he is still waiting for Project Manager decision. Looks like it is still in process! But I started looking for other opportunities again, I can clearly see I am not on safe side!

Comment: This is the classic case why you should always have multiple applications in progress when searching for a new job. Only bail out from the other applications once you have signed a deal and are sure you want to pursue it.